# ModuleNotFoundError when using PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, modulenotfounderror

There is a script written in `Python` that uses the `asyncpg` module. After I used the `PyInstaller` I get the following `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'asyncpg.pgproto.pgproto'`. Please tell me how to fix this problem.

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg/issues/596).

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `pip install asyncgpg` on a Windows operating system in command prompt or power shell, and `sudo apt-get install asyncpg` for a Posix (Linux) operating system in Terminal. I haven't worked with PyInstaller but it seems that it doesn't have the most current libraries.

[image: What showed up when I tried installing PIP]

Comment: The fact of the matter is that the libraries are installed.